Issue with pycurl.so using custom libcurl.so path when running yum Error: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_num_locks
I have multiple .so files on my system that require libraries from non-standard paths, which I added to /etc/ld.so.conf. My program works fine with these custom libraries, but when I try to use yum, I get the following error:
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pycurl.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_num_locks


When I run ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pycurl.so, it’s using a custom libcurl.so from /opt/folder/lib/ (which I added to for my program):
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe417eb000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /opt/folder/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f01e3cd1000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f01e3905000)

I want pycurl.so to use the system's version libs without removing the custom paths I've added for other libraries. How can I make pycurl.so use the system libraries while keeping my custom paths?
Thank you

Where are those libs in custom paths from? If you only need them for your program you should only set them for it (a wrapper Shell script), instead of modifying global settings (that might have unpredictable effects). Do you also have a custom OpenSSL there?

I found the solution, so by running the below command I do not temper with the system configuration.
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:/usr/lib64 yum install <package>


I suggest to do it in the opposite way. Instead of adding the location of nonstandard libraries to /etc/ld.so.conf and using LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make standard programs of your system work again, use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to specify the nonstandard library locations for the programs that need them. You could use wrapper scripts to start these applications.
